# What is the verb for the action of a coward?

Tags: single-word-requests

I wonder what the verb for the action of a "coward" is.

I remember there seems to be a verb form similar to *coward*, but *coward* cannot be a verb.

Comment: I would rephrase the sentence to use `cowardly` but that doesn't the question :P

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"**Cower**" may be the verb you remember. One of its meanings is "to sink through fear".

Comment: More to the point, a perfectly good definition of "coward" is "one who cowers".

Answer (score 12):

Cowards are multifaceted!

In addition to cowering, they can flee, retreat, shy away, recoil, flinch, hide, quail, tremble, shrink, wilt, blanch, wet themselves...

Answer (score 9):

The coward displays cowardice. He or she commits an act of cowardice. Cowards behave in a cowardly manner. If especially egregious, the act in question is craven.

Answer (score 2):

There’s ‘funk’ meaning ‘to flinch or shrink through fear’. In the US, apparently, ‘flink’, means ‘to behave in a cowardly manner’. (OED)

Comment: I'm from the US, and I've never heard "flink". "Fink", on the other hand, means to rat someone out.

Comment: Yes, it only "apparently" means that. I've never, ever heard it (as a Canadian, mind you).